# jQuery Datatables - cells added via rowGroup always get colspan over all cols. How can i change this behaviour?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, datatables

I added grouping functionality to my dataTable and because of this I added the following code to my settings:

```js
rowGroup: {
            startRender: null,
            endRender: function (rows, group) {
                var hoursPerGroup = rows
                    .data()
                    .pluck('istarbeit')
                    .reduce( function (a, b) {
                        return a + b;
                    }, 0);
                hoursPerGroup = $.fn.dataTable.render.number().display(hoursPerGroup);
                
                return $('<tr/>')
                    .append('<td>' + group + '</td>')
                    .append('<td>' + hoursPerGroup + '</td>');
            },
            dataSrc: 'aufnr'
        }
```

now I have the problem, that all the `<td>` Tags are added with `colspan="17"`. Is there anything I can do to prevent this behaviour? How can I overwrite this?

[Rendered Code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uT8H8.png)

I tried googling this problem, but was not able to find a fitting solution. Even in the documentation it was done in pretty much the same way with custom colspan and it worked. But not in my case.

I'm hoping somone can help me with this :) Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

When switching pages in the dataTable, the colspan goes away most of the time, but resizing the browser window brings it back immediately. I guess it has something to do with the **responsive extension** for the datatable which I am using?

Comment: So how many cells do your already existing table rows have at this point then? If that's more than two - then _what sense_ would it make, to insert a new row with just _two_ columns, that are not even allowed to span?

Comment: There are 17 columns altogether, and I want to add custom colspan to each cell (of the "grouped" row) so they do not overflow the table. Right now the second cell with the value is outside of the table, because the first cell spans over the whole table.

Addition: I just discovered that going to different pages suddenly removes the colspan.